# Download directory structure explanation - Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

When downloading Ubuntu(Desktop version), for example
Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak) Netboot.

After choosing arhitecture for example (i386) download directory opens and there is list of files:

[image: DownloadDirImg]

Index of /ubuntu/dists/yakkety-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot

- boot.img.gz
- ldlinux.c32
- mini.iso
- netboot.tar.gz
- pxelinux.0
- pxelinux.cfg/
- ubuntu-installer/
- xen/

Where can I find explanation what is the meaning of those files ad which one is correct for me ?

Comment: Correct for doing what?

Comment: Install Ubuntu on my local Windows laptop, make bootable USB or CD

Comment: Well, unless you have some specific need for using netboot, don't use it for general installations. Use the standard desktop image.

Comment: So instead of Network installer i should go to Other images ( choose some country mirror (Germany) ) and download ubuntu-16.10-desktop-i386.iso  ? Why is this Network installer on top of that page ?

Comment: Yes. However, unless you have very old hardware, pick the amd64 image. And you can probably just use the download links from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop (you can skip the donation page)

Comment: It's top of that page because those are alternative downloads, for people have different use cases and know what they want.

Comment: I tested the Mini image in Virtualbox and it gave me errors but looks interesting :)